# problems with understanding generics

Tags: java, generics

I have wrote the following code:

```
public class Test
{   
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException 
    {
        System.out.println(new Generic<Integer>("one").type);  //outputs "one"
    }
}

class Generic<T>
{
    public T type;

    public Generic(Object obj)
    {
        type = (T)obj;
    }
}
```

And i thought i will get an exception while doing the cast, but i didnt. I get the output: "one". But if i do `new generic<Integer>`, `type` become a variable of type Integer, so how can i cast the `String` `"one"` to `T` and store it in the variable `type` in my `generic` class without getting an exception? An explanation would be great.

Comment: Please name classes with an upper-case first letter.

Comment: You cannot. "one" is not an Integer, and cannot be cast to an Integer. Also, your generic function isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exception because [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) removes any checking of the `Integer` type from your code. Since [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) takes `Object` the compiler doesn't need to insert a cast, and the code simply erases to:

```
System.out.println(new Generic("one").type);
```

Try the following assignment instead:

```
Integer i = new Generic<Integer>("one").type;
```

In that case you'll get a `ClassCastException` because the code erases to:

```
Integer i = (Integer)new Generic("one").type;
```

Notice that switching the types behaves differently. This will throw a `ClassCastException`:

```
System.out.println(new Generic<String>(123).type);
```

That's because the [`println(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) overload is used, so the code erases to:

```
System.out.println((String)new Generic(123).type);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of java type erasure:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

basically java will replace T with Object (if T has no bounding upper type like in your example)- and everything is fine at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is not casting your string to integer....because it is unbound. It is converting the T to object instead and in the sysout you are getting obj.toString instead.

The proper way would be as below and automatically you will get compile exception in your test class... as expected.

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public T type;

    public Generic(T t)
    {
        type = t;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public T type;

    public Generic(T obj)
    {
        type = obj;
    }
}
```

There. Fixed it for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why a `ClassCastException` wasn't thrown.

Comment: Because casting to Object never throws a ClassCastException?